# Помогите получить значение из словаря

Tags: python

Помогите получить значение из словаря, который появляется при выполнении команды, и вывести его. Я хочу получить значение "buyprice", которое стоит первым после "last_exec_price", т.е. 0.04995

**order = session.get_active_order(symbol="RVNUSDT")**

{'ret_code': 0,
'ret_msg': 'OK',
'ext_code': '',
'ext_info': '',
'result': {'current_page': 1,
'data': [{'order_id': '6c4102b3-e42b-4a50-a64d-f987aa11e9bc',
'user_id': 36805748,
'symbol': 'RVNUSDT',
'side': 'Buy',
'order_type': 'Market',
'price': 0.0524,
'qty': 10,
'time_in_force': 'ImmediateOrCancel',
'order_status': 'Filled',
'last_exec_price': 0.04995,
'cum_exec_qty': 10,
'cum_exec_value': 0.4995,
'cum_exec_fee': 0.0002997,
'reduce_only': False,
'close_on_trigger': False,
'order_link_id': '',
'created_time': '2022-09-16T14:21:03Z',
'updated_time': '2022-09-16T14:21:03Z',
'take_profit': 0,
'stop_loss': 0,
'tp_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN',
'sl_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN'}

**buyprice = ...**

Comment: А вы уверенны, что это словарь?

Comment: точно не знаю что это, но значение получить как то надо

Comment: Опускайтесь во вложенное каскадом [‘то-то][‘се-то]….. можете каждый раз делать принт и смотреть, что осталось. Так и дойдёте, надеюсь.

Answer (score 0):

В следующий раз просьба оформлять код верно в вопросе: не забудьте выделить его с помощью апострофов с двух сторон(Пример: `код`)

Итак, давайте посмотрим на структуру `order`. Вы получили словарь, проверить это можно с помощью функции `type(order)`.
Убедившись, что это словарь, вы должны с помощью ключа получить значение. Понимаем, что заправшиваемое Вами значение `last_exec_price` находится в `result` -> `data` -> `last_exec_price`

Внимание! **При использовании ключа `'data'` Вы получаете список**, поэтому дальше вам нужно получать значения уже по индексам(Индексация начинается с нуля, поэтому получаем значение с помощью `data[0]`).

Дальше мы получаем ещё один словарь, по ключу `last_exec_price` получаем желанное значение `0.04995`.

Полное решение прикладываю ниже:

```py
res = {'ret_code': 0, 'ret_msg': 'OK', 'ext_code': '', 'ext_info': '', 'result': {'current_page': 1, 'data': [
    {'order_id': '6c4102b3-e42b-4a50-a64d-f987aa11e9bc', 'user_id': 36805748, 'symbol': 'RVNUSDT', 'side': 'Buy',
     'order_type': 'Market', 'price': 0.0524, 'qty': 10, 'time_in_force': 'ImmediateOrCancel', 'order_status': 'Filled',
     'last_exec_price': 0.04995, 'cum_exec_qty': 10, 'cum_exec_value': 0.4995, 'cum_exec_fee': 0.0002997,
     'reduce_only': False, 'close_on_trigger': False, 'order_link_id': '', 'created_time': '2022-09-16T14:21:03Z',
     'updated_time': '2022-09-16T14:21:03Z', 'take_profit': 0, 'stop_loss': 0, 'tp_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN',
     'sl_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN'}]}}

buyprice = res['result']['data'][0]['last_exec_price']
```

Не забудьте принять ответ.

Удачи!